# Sails.js: Add Controller name and function to log entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, morgan

I am customizing morgan logging in sails.js v0.12.3 and I am able to enrich log entries by introducing new morgan tokens based on properties on the req object - fine.

Specifically we want to log the controller and its function called.

**A target log entry would be:**

`UserController - find - GET /api/v1/users 200 125.952 ms - -`

Currently we have a separate log statement that is written directly by the Controller function. But with some load they do not appear right after each other. So we want to have these information together in one log entry.

**My initial attempt:**

When I log req.options.controller, it always outputs 'session'. I guess that is because of my order of middlewares in http.js.

`order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cachePreflights',
      'morgan',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],`

But putting `morgan` after `router` leads to NO morgan output at all.

Do you have any idea that makes this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding,

1. Controller is decided and called by `router`.
   Hence controller is 'session' (or something generic / undefined) before `router` kicks in.
2. Response is returned by `router` in case of non-404, non-500 requests.
   Hence, middleware (`morgan`) is not triggered, if it is after `router`.

Also response time is not known until response is prepared.

### Solution

Keep your middleware before `router` in `order`.
Use request's `end` event to print logs.

```
logRequestDetails: function(req, res, next) {
  req.on("end", function() {
    sails.log.verbose('Request', req.options.controller, req.options.action);
  });
},
```